# Computing block sum for an arbitrary region in an image

Tags: algorithm

I wonder what is the most effective way to solve the following problem:
(If there is a name for this problem, I would like to know it as well)

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0;
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0;
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0;
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1;
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0;
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0;
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0;
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0;
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0;
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

If I have an image where I am interested in the following pixels marked by 1. In an image I want to calculate a sum around this block. A sum of block is easy to calculate from an integral image but I don't want to do it for the whole image, since there is a lot of unnecessary computation.

One option that I can come up with is to search the minimum and maximum in horizontal and vertical directions and then take a rectangular portion of the image enlarged so that it will covered the block portion. For example +2 pixels each directions, if the block size is 5. But this solution still includes unnecessary calculation.

If I had a list of these indices, I could loop through them and calculate the sum for each block but then if there is another pixel close by which has the same pixels in its block, I need to recalculate them and If I save them, I somehow need to look if they are already calculated or not and that takes time as well.

Is there a known solution for this sort of a problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "sum around this block". How do you define the requirement in exact terms? Can you give some examples?

Comment: What I got from this question is you are looking, for each pixel, the sum of the values of all the pixels within N Manhattan distance from that pixel. In otherwords, to convolute your image with a NxN matrix consisting entirely of 1s. Is this right?

Comment: @François Andrieux:
for each pixel, the sum of the values of all the pixels within N Manhattan distance from that pixel -> yes ... In otherwords, to convolute your image with a NxN matrix consisting entirely of 1s. Is this right? -> I am not sure if this is the same thing

Comment: @Pedro If your images are sparse, then it may be worth it to determine a region of interest (a region where there is relevant data). Though you will need to try the approach and measure the performance yourself. Practically, it's very difficult to predict rather an optimization is worth it's overhead without trying it.

Comment: @François Andrieux: Thank you, that's what I expected as well, was just keeping hopes that if there is a better solution which I just haven't thought of :)

Comment: Performing an operation on a submatrix is a common requirement.  Masking is also a common requirement.  Fuzzy operations (those that bleed into nearby pixels) are also a common requirement.  I think you'll find what you're doing well-supported by any matrix library that gives ANY thought to image processing.  I'm not sure you care to use a library, but it seemed worth mentioning.

Comment: @zzxyz: Thank you, do you have any suggestions or examples to find libraries that have already implemented solutions for these fuzzy operations? Googling "image processing fuzzy operations" only gives me results about fuzzy logic but I am not interested of that.

Comment: @Pedro Eigen or MKL. I’ve never used either, because I haven’t done matrix stuff in decades, but I’d be shocked if either doesn’t support this stuff